# Converting RA-Dec to galactc coordinate(l,b)

Tags: coordinates, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation, astropy

I want to convert (RA,Dec) coordinate to galactic (l,b) coordinate using astropy.

Here are my script.

```
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord

RA=12.5039167

Dec=25.301945

c=SkyCoord(RA, Dec, unit='deg')
l=c.galactic.l.degree
b=c.galactic.b.degree

print(l,b)
```

As a result, I get

```
122.52637037749905 -37.56868264034257
```

I know this is wrong because When I put in to a calculator in website,
[https://www.astrouw.edu.pl/~jskowron/ra-dec/?q=12.5039167+25.301945](https://www.astrouw.edu.pl/%7Ejskowron/ra-dec/?q=12.5039167+25.301945)

I get Something like 232.??, 84.?? (The unit is dms, so it is technically little bit different from degree.) And I know this should be the right answer.

How should I fix my script to get correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out myself.

Actually the formula given on the astropy is correct.

The problem which I got was because I was having confusion with hour and degree.

The range for degree is [0,360), however, range for hour would be [0,24). Which means that I have to convert 1 hour to 15 degree first! (Same with min and sec. multiply 15!)